# ggplot split bars by percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tibble...

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Variable Correlation Type  Percentage
  <fct>          <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>
1 Bar1            0.16 A            0.7
2 Bar1            0.16 B           NA  
3 Bar1            0.16 C            0.3
4 Bar2            0.17 A            0.1
5 Bar2            0.17 B           NA  
6 Bar2            0.17 C            0.9
7 Bar3            0.17 A            0.1
8 Bar3            0.17 B            0.6
9 Bar3            0.17 C            0.3
```

I want a barplot with Variable on the x-axis and the correlation on the y-axis.

It should only have 3 bars for the x-axis (Bar1, Bar2, Bar3) with y-axis values of .16, .17, .17.

I want to split the 3 bars by Type into A, B and C percentages. For example, Bar1 would be 70% A and 30% C.

So far I have the following...

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = Variable, y = Correlation/3, fill = Type)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity")
```

But this just splits the bars evenly into A, B and C. I can't work out how to incorporate the percentages as well.

[image: Plot attempt]

Comment: so you want to have a bar of height "correlation" which is filled according to "percentage", right?

Comment: Yep, height should be .16, .17, .17 respectively. Fill should equal the percentage for A, B and C.

Comment: then, I think, Allan Cameron was faster then me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the stacked bars to *add* to the correlation value, so you should plot the correlation *times* the percentage (more accurately the *proportion*) on the y axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable, y = Percentage * Correlation, fill = Type)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(y = "Correlation")
```

[image]